# Executando jar no cliente a partir do navegador

Tags: php, java, jar

Eu preciso executar um arquivo jar que deve estar no pc do cliente pela web e passar alguns parâmetros pra esse jar, eu consegui fazer isso com o `exec()` do php:

```
exec('java -jar "C:\Users\Suporte01\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Printer\dist\Printer.jar" Hello', $output);
print_r($output);
```

porém ele executa o jar no servidor...

**EDIT**

Seria algo como eu vejo algumas aplicações web fazerem como o `logmein`, que abre direto do navegador um programa de acesso remoto que fica instalado no seu computador, como pode ser visto a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que é necessário ter algum serviço instalado no cliente?

Comment: Deixando um link aqui que talvez ajude no futuro :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922225/how-to-use-php-exec-to-run-jar-with-input-parameters

Comment: Cara, faz o seguinte, joga o jar no cliente e cria um link no navegador para abrir uma página acessando um servidor instalado no cliente e faz este servidor"cliente" invocar o jar... to pesquisando como fazer também e acabei de ter esta ideia... ainda nem testei! tomara que funcione!

Answer (score 6):

O `exec()` do PHP executa um comando **server-side**, já que não é uma linguagem **client-side**.

#### Executando um JAR pelo navegador

Para executar um [jar](/questions/tagged/jar) no navegador, como você deseja, o que eu indicaria é utilizar uma [applet](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet#Utiliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o_em_Java), como é vista nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5104850/1606920) e chamá-la pelo javascript, como no exemplo a seguir:

```html
<applet name="myapp" archive="myjar.jar" code="com.company.MyApplet"/>
<script>
   var result = myapp.foo();
</script>
```

#### Executando um JAR que está no computador do cliente pelo Internet Explorer

Outra possibilidade, depois de ver o que você queria a partir da edição da questão, é requisitar, através de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), que o cliente rode o [jar](/questions/tagged/jar) pelo `ActiveXObject`, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16413048/1606920). O exemplo para rodar é esse:

```js
function RunExe(){  
  var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var myJar = 'C://WindowJar.jar'; //exemplo
  w.run(myJar);//Roda o jar
  return true;
}
```

Caso você queira trabalhar algum retorno do arquivo executado, você pode utilizar o seguinte exemplo:

```js
function RunExe(){  
  var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var myJar = 'C://WindowJar.jar'; //exemplo
  var ex = w.run(myJar);//Roda o jar
  var ret = "";
  //lê a saída do jar
  while (!ex.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
    ret += ex.StdOut.ReadLine();
  }
  //Dá um alert no retorno
  alert(ret)
  return true;
}
```

#### Executando um JAR que está no computador do cliente usando protocolos

Outra alternativa, não indicada por questões de segurança, é utilizar [protocolos URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx), o que significa mexer nos registros da máquina alvo. Segundo esse [exemplo](http://openwinforms.com/run_exe_from_javascript.html), é possível alcançar esse objetivo da seguinte forma:

**Criar um protocolo personolizado**

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\protocolname]
@="URL: descricao"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\protocolname\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\protocolname\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\protocolname\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Path to\\Jar\\myJar.jar\" %1"
```

**Utilizar uma tag de referência no HTML**

```
<a href="protocolname:parameter-value">link</a>
```

No entanto, pode ser retirado da documentação supracitado o seguinte:

> **Security Alert**  Applications that handle URL protocols must consider how to respond to malicious data. Because handler applications can receive data from untrusted sources, the URL and other parameter values passed to the application may contain malicious data that attempts to exploit the handling application.

Em tradução livre:

> **Alerta de Segurança**  Aplicações que manipulam protocolos URL devem considerar como responder a dados maliciosos. Porque o manipulador da aplicação pode receber dados de fontes não confiáveis, a URL ou outros valores de parâmetros passados para a aplicação podem conter dados maliciosos que tentam explorar a aplicação manipulada.

Logo, se não for estritamente necessário utilizar outro browser, indico utilizar o Internet Explorer com o `ActiveXObject`, por ser mais simples e menos perigoso do que criar um protocolo personalizado.

Comment: Então @Felipe Avelar tentei fazer o mesmo usando um applet porem quando executo o applet direto pelo netbeans ele funciona normalmente puxando as impressoras instaladas no cliente que é o que preciso, mais ao executar no navegador ele não as puxa..

Comment: Cara, o que você precisa é só imprimir ou é pegar todas as impressoras? Se eu não me engano, uma applet não vai ter permissão pra requisitar as impressoras de um cliente...

Comment: Então preciso imprimir um RAW DOCUMENT... preciso ser capaz de pelo menos abrir o print dialog do windows, mas o jeito certo mesmo seria executar a aplicação no cliente, tipo esse exemplo da imagem

Comment: Se for uma página HTML que você vai imprimir, porque não usar o método de impressão do próprio browser, usando o `window.print()`?

Comment: Exato não é uma pagina html que vou imprimir, preciso imprimir em formato EPL em um impressora zebra, não posso enviar um documento html para impressão...

Comment: Exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308412/sending-a-barcode-to-a-zebra-printer-from-a-java-application

Comment: Estou apenas especulando, por isso o comentário, mas e se você armazenasse o JAR no *local storage* do browser e usasse o path local desse arquivo, agora no PC do cliente, como argumento para esse ActiveX do Felipe?

Comment: ao executar o codigo ele retorna um erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined `

Comment: Essa opção só funciona para o Internet Exeplorer, vou editar minha resposta com outra alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

O jar *sempre* será executado no lado do servidor. O que você tem que fazer é capturar o output da execução e enviá-lo para o lado do cliente.

Acho que o mais sábio, nesse caso, seria colocar seu jar dentro de um serviço web, e esse serviço oferecer uma API REST para que outros serviços conversem com ele via HTTP.

Comment: Não teria como pois estou utilizando o java para ter acesso as impressoras do cliente...

Answer (score 1):

Para rodar um JAR no cliente você tem algumas opções:

- Java Web Start - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start;
- Java Applet - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet.

Este site contém comparações entre os dois métodos: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javawebstart.html#APPLETSVSJWS.

É tudo em Inglês, então eu vou tentar enumerar as principais diferenças e semelhanças aqui:

- Ambos rodam em um ambiente "restrito" se o JAR não for assinado digitalmente;
- Para poder accessar áreas restritas, você precisa descrever o que vai fazer, e assinar o JAR;
- Um applet roda no browser, o Java web start parece uma aplicação remota, mas ela é baixada de um servidor automaticamente.

A última opção seria "dar" o JAR para o cliente e pedir para ele rodar diretamente no cliente, e você poderia accessar o seu servidor para fazer o upload das informações que você precisa - neste caso, o seu JAR teria acesso irrestrito ao que o usuário pode ver (ao menos sem as restrições de um applet ou aplicação Java Web Start).